# Not getting value on VFpage outputtext? Trying to do simple calculation on <apex:outputtext value="">

Tags: visualforce

I am doing simple calculation to get the value on VFPage but it doesn't come up with any value.

below is the example

```
<apex:column headervalue="SLMTotal"
<apex:outputtext value="{!(slm.field1+slm.field2+slm.field3)*(slm.field4)}"/>
</apex:column>
```

I have checked slm.field4 does have value so it is not X 0 error.

What could it be? Does any one please suggest?

Comment: what is slm, can you paste the controller

Comment: slm stands fro opportunity standard object

Comment: do you see just blank, it will be helpful If you can paste how you are populating the slm. I see no issue as such with the way you are calculating the value of the outputtext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of the fields is blank, then the entire expression will be evaluated as a blank. i.e. blanks will not be treated as zeros.

The following expression should work.

```
<apex:column headervalue="SLMTotal"
    <apex:outputtext value="{!(NULLVALUE(slm.field1,0)+NULLVALUE(slm.field2,0)+NULLVALUE(slm.field3,0))*(NULLVALUE(slm.field4,0))}"/>
</apex:column>
```

The function NULLVALUE() replaces nulls with an alternate expression, in this case with zero.

Comment: Oh is it really? Let me try this.